# Cannot pass big blob/clob data to the procedure using oci sql driver

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, clob, oci8

We have a application which is using oracle procedure to send emails. Procedure takes a few arguments as parameters. If I send 22kb data as CLOB to the procedure, it is failing to send email and the error I see is - `ORA-23620: bind value size too large for PL/SQL CALL operation`.

If I `EXEC` the same procedure in oracle client it sends email. It seems to be issue with OCI8.

how do I fix it?.

Comment: please provide the procedure, at least the parameter definition.
please provide the OCI8 code you do, including variable definition.
please provide the EXEC code.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-23620: bind value size too large for PL/SQL CALL operation
Cause: In a PL/SQL CALL to a stored procedure, the bind string size exceeded
4K.
Action: Either make the bind string size shorter (less than 4K) or use BEGIN-END
to call the procedure instead of CALL.

Comment: I have defined the variable as CLOB in the procedure. I think it is not even going to the procedure. This error is given by OCI8 drivers.

Comment: Anyways, the reason is same.

Comment: what if I break the data into 5 variables and join them in procedure, will that work?.

Comment: like explained : Either make the bind string size shorter (less than 4K) or use BEGIN-END to call the procedure instead of CALL.
it means that doing:
BEGIN
 myprocedure(parameters);
END;
/
will work

Comment: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested is the error I am getting now. any clues?

Comment: This time I think it is directly inside the procedure but without the code it is difficult to say.

Comment: like `$query->bindValue('emailAttachFileName', $attachFileName);` If I try to bind it with `$query->bindValue('emailAttachContent', $attachFileDataEncoded);`, since `$attachFileDataEncoded` is large-22KB, it is giving error

Comment: can you share the whole code used to insert your data?

Comment: query->bindValue('emailAttachContent', $attachFileDataEncoded,'blob'); is the simple solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for this is adding type of data as parameter while binding.

```
query->bindValue('emailAttachContent', $attachFileDataEncoded,'blob');
```

This fixed the issue. OCI now understands that this field is carrying blob data. Earlier it assumed `varchar2` which is default to 4000. i.e. 4kb.